# Help with SOQL Query Containing NOT and other arguments in WHERE clause

Tags: soql

For Some reason I keep receiving query errors when running the following query:

```
SELECT id, createddate, ownerID, owner.name, subject, whoid, whatid from Task WHERE NOT(subject LIKE '%pardot%') AND CreatedDate >= 2017-10-01T00:00:00Z
```

If I run the query with just one of the WHERE arguments, it works, but not when I have both as above.

So, the following two queries work:

1.

```
SELECT id, createddate, ownerID, owner.name, subject, whoid, whatid from Task WHERE NOT(subject LIKE '%pardot%')
```

2.

```
SELECT id, createddate, ownerID, owner.name, subject, whoid, whatid from Task WHERE CreatedDate >= 2017-10-01T00:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was that the "NOT" operator had to be *inside* the parentheses. Thus, the following SOQL query works:

```
SELECT id, createddate, ownerID, owner.name, subject, whoid, whatid from Task WHERE CreatedDate >= 2017-10-01T00:00:00Z and (not subject LIKE '%pardot%')
```

Of course I get the answer immediately after asking for help, but not before spending an hour trying to figure it out...

Comment: I'm not entirely certain of the differences (if any), but there is a `NOT LIKE` operator. Additionally, `LIKE '%thing%'` (generally anything of the form `LIKE '%<string>'`) generally kills SOQL performance (SOQL processing time doesn't count towards the CPU governor limit, but the delay is still something your users will experience), so I'd advise finding an alternative if possible. The only saving grace here is that `CreatedDate` tends to be an indexed field, so I'd expect Salesforce's query optimizations to be able to handle this (and generally say that your query is selective).

Comment: @DerekF Thanks for the note! I'll give `NOT LIKE` a try and good to know about the wildcard performance penalty.